# Site freeze showing after preloading amp runtime on iPhone

Tags: amp-html, preload

## What's the issue?

For the best practice, recently I have implemented the Preload technique to load AMP runtime with high priority and loaded the runtime script later on with async.

The problem is, after implementing this changes sometime site freeze issue producing on iPhone Safari browser. If I have cleared the safari browser cache and start browsing my site, then site doesn't work like the amp state binding related section not working. seems amp-state variable bind does not working although site loaded completely, so some logic or action related to any operation with amp-state variable define totally not working.

## How do we reproduce the issue?

If I  have cleared the iPhone safari browser cache, then start browsing my site. site loaded showing but while I clicked on some section on my web page where amp-state bind related operation exist,it doesn’t work totally. seems site freeze with no operation happen and it's feel like nothing working.

Then if I reload again & again after sometimes it works. Seems sometime amp-state variable bind not set properly, Although site is fully AMP validated with successful result.

Why this happen and how this freeze could be solved? Any suggestion please?

Comment: Can you please add a link to your site.

Comment: Can't not share my web page link due to privacy issue. @SebastianBenz are you clear about the issue from my writing above? in a short if i cleared my iPhone browser cache and start browsing the site, then sometime site dynamic section not work, its totally freeze. if i refresh time to time and sometime site dynamic section works. Dynamic section means the section on a page with amp-state define variable manipulation or logic implementation to complete a action based on user activity at user end